# Showing that an extension field has the specific form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $\gamma$ stand for the real 9th root of 5, and let $L = {\bf Q}(\gamma)$.  Suppose that ${\bf Q} \subsetneq K \subsetneq L$.  Then $[L : K] = [K : {\bf Q}] = 3$.

Why must $K = {\bf Q}(\gamma^3)$?

The minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $K$ has degree 3, and it is a divisor of $x^9 - 5$ in $K[x]$.

Comment: What is $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$? What restrictions does that impose on $K$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to show that any such $ K $ would contain $ \gamma^3 $. To prove this, note that the conjugates of $ \gamma $ over $ \mathbf Q $, and thus over $ K $ are all of the form $ \zeta^k \gamma $ for $ \zeta $ a primitive ninth root of unity. The field norm $ N_{L/K} $ then sends $ \gamma $ to $ \zeta^k \gamma^3 $ for some value of $ k $ ($ \gamma $ has three distinct $ K $-conjugates, and the norm is the product of those conjugates). Since $ K $ is a real field, this value of $ k $ can only be a multiple of $ 9 $; since all other powers of $ \zeta $ have nonzero imaginary parts. Thus, $ N_{L/K}(\gamma) = \gamma^3 $, and since the norm map is a map $ L \to K $, it follows that $ \gamma^3 \in K $.

Comment: Just a question here: Can't we use the fact that identity map is the only automorpshism of $L$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q} $? This would constrain the number of intermediate fields $K$ to be $1$ and then the conclusion follows.

Comment: How does that imply that there is only one intermediate field?

Comment: Well I am myself a novice in these matters. What I think is that if we have two distinct fields $K_{1}=\mathbb{Q} (a) ,K_{2}=\mathbb{Q} (b) $ lying between $\mathbb{Q} $ and $L$ then there is an automorpshism $\phi$ of $L$ with $\phi(a) =b$.

Comment: I am trying to think in terms of conjugate intermediate fields and perhaps that approach is also feasible here.

Comment: Why do you think that two intermediate fields have to be conjugate?

Comment: Ok let me express my thoughts which may not be rigorous and perhaps you can help make it rigorous. The field $L$ does not have any other roots of $x^9-5=0 $ and hence there is only one automorpshism of $L$ the identity map. Under this situation we can only have a linear chain of inclusions of intermediate fields. Thus if we draw a graph of all intermediate fields including both $Q$ and $L$ and the inclusion be denoted by directed arrows, then we will have only one path from $Q$ to $L$ via intermediate fields. For multiple paths from $Q$ to $L$ we must have non-trivial automorpshisms of $L$.

Comment: Do you think there is a theorem in Galois theory which sort of conveys the idea I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: I think we also need the assumption that $L$ is a finite extension of $Q$ for the above to work. Otherwise the field of reals has enough counter-examples.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If translated to a group theory problem, what you're saying is "If $ G $ is a finite group with a subgroup $ H $ such that $ N_G(H) = H $, then the subgroups of $ G $ containing $ H $ must form a linear chain with respect to inclusion." I am not sure what made you think of this claim, but $ G = S_5 $ and $ H  = \langle (12345) \rangle $ is a counterexample. (The copies of $ GA(1, 5) $ and $ A_5 $ containing $ (12345) $ can't be put into a linear chain.)

Comment: Ok then maybe I am on wrong track. I will try to learn more stuff. Thanks for helping me out with my confused ideas.